# About the proof of Theorem 6 in Chapter 27 in "Calculus" by Michael Spivak. Is this inequality really not obivious?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, power-series

I am reading "Calculus" by Michael Spivak.

Spivak proved that the following inequality holds for sufficiently large $N$:
$$|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{((z+h)^n-z^n)}{h}-\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \frac{((z+h)^n-z^n)}{h}| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$

But I think this inequality is obvious because
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \frac{(z+h)^n}{h} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{(z+h)^n}{h},$$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \frac{z^n}{h} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{z^n}{h}.$$

I cannot understand what Spivak is doing.

Is this inequality really not obvious?

[image]

Comment: Roughly speaking, the problem is that you have two variables, $N$ and $h$. Yes, for fixed $h$, if the series converges, then the existence of $N$ follows from the definition. Notice in the conclusion, the word all is italicized to indicate the convergence is uniform in $h$. And by uniform in $h$, I mean that you can place a neighborhood around $h$ so that $N$ is then chosen independent of $h$.

Comment: @zugzug Thank you very much. Now I understand what Spivak is doing thanks to you.